# What are the main visual differences between Spitfires and Hurricanes?

Tags: aircraft-identification

I've heard that Supermarine Spitfires and Hawker Hurricanes were both great fighters, but what are their distinguishing features?

Comment: Albeit having _photos_ in the title, the linked duplicate should answer your question.

Comment: What can we tell you that isn't apparent in the pictures?

Comment: I'm not sure which plane is which.

Comment: The Hurricane has a humpy back and a cockpit like a greenhouse; the Spitfire doesn't have these things. I have known that since I was aged about 8.

Comment: The top one is a Hurricane, the one on the bottom is a Spitfire.  Study them.  A picture is worth a thousand words, and no amount of words will help if you can't distinguish them visually yourself.